# Componentes para Integration Services - SSIS - Data Flow

Tags: sql-server, integração, ssis, componentes

Olá! Tenho uma necessidade de desenvolver um componente para o Integration Services (SSIS) -> Data Flow.

Já tenho componentes desenvolvidos para o a área do Control Flow, mas nunca desenvolvi nada para Data Flow. Tentei achar alguma coisa sobre esse tipo de componente na web mas não tive sucesso.

Se alguém souber algum tutorial ou exemplo, agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente esse tutorial. Está em inglês mas é bem explicado

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/211/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-data-flow/